# What technology does ie6 have that legacy system must require it?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, legacy, policy, corporate-policy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is IE6 still a corporate favorite in some organizations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681440/why-is-ie6-still-a-corporate-favorite-in-some-organizations)

As of July 2010, IE6 browser usage is still lingering at around 7%. ([w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp)) It's well known that *most* installations of IE6 are coming from companies that have internal software systems that absolutely require the use of Internet Explorer 6 and have the browser installed on most if not all machines at said institution.

What is it exactly about these systems that they have to use this browser to run their software?

Some initial thoughts I had were:

1. Relying on IE6's implementation of CSS for proper page rendering.
2. Relying on IE6's implementation of Javascript that takes care of page logic.
3. Special .NET web controls specific to IE6.
4. IE6 extensions/plugins required for the web app to process properly.
5. Security restrictions imposed in IE6.

What are some cases you all have seen out in the wild?

Comment: @Gert True. I missed that one during my prior searches. However, in defense, this question is aimed more at uncovering any technical requirements legacy system need from IE6 that may not be supported in newer grade A browsers.

Comment: IE6's market share is closer to 17% (using a web design page as a source isn't necessarily representative of the general internet). See http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2

Comment: I don't really think this is an "exact duplicate" of the linked question above. This one is aimed at what technical requirements are in ie6 that make legacy systems absolutely require it. It's a web browser, why cant the old systems use ie7 or ie8?

Comment: @Catchwa - check http://w3counter.com/globalstats.php an analytics software pulling stats across all their accounts show IE6 at 6.27% I can pull other numbers if you are interested also.

Comment: Also note - (from netmarketshare http://is.gd/fc5MC) Share of the nearly decade-old Internet Explorer 6 fell below 5% in Europe and is nearing 5% in many developed markets such as U.S., UK and France.  The major holdout for IE6 is China with over 46% share (50.5% if you include editions), which is significantly skewing global share.

Answer (score 3):

Some internal web apps might rely on ActiveX, which only works in Internet Explorer (as far as I know). (So that would be an instance of item 4. on your list.)

Comment: but are these activex controls dependent on IE6? Isn't activex available in all versions of IE?

Comment: Yeah that’s true, although I’m not sure if particular ActiveX controls are targeted at specific browser versions. It might just be that the company who supplied the control guaranteed it contractually to work on IE6, and made no such guarantee for future browsers, so why risk breaking something.

Answer (score 2):

It's not only that these programs were written specifically for IE6, but the cost of upgrading all their internal software when it "works" (heavy emphasis on the quotes) causes most upper management to invest money elsewhere, especially in today's economy.

Comment: Although this really isn't aimed at the point of this question. Looking for technical reasons not management/organization issues.

Comment: Do you think anyone with no financial limits would choose IE6 over newer browsers? With personal experience within my the company I work for not upgrading for this exact reason, I'm lead to believe it's primarily people not associated directly with the warm fuzzy feelings towards old technology but rather with the cost of the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Various theories:

- As Paul states, legacy technologies like active X or MS's old version of JAVA run time
- IE 6 had very broken CSS rendering, so anything written to 'only look right' in IE6 with CSS likely breaks badly in all the other browsers
- Sloppy/lazy developers who wrote IE6 apps rather than Web Apps
- Sloppy/lazy upper management o paid for IE6 apps rather than Web Apps
- Apathy in internal IT departments preventing desktop upgrades
- Apathy in upper management to keep front-line hardware actually up to date

Answer (score 0):

7. Vendor has not certified/tested their software for the newer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Most resistance to upgrades I've seen has come from users who can't be taught new tricks, such as having to adjust to a control being in a different spot on a new version of the software.

The IT department can work its butt off testing/rolling out software all it wants, but if the users don't like it, the rollout will fail, no matter how much better/faster/cleaner/securer the new version is.

Answer (score 0):

Governments (UK, Argentina, most LA) validating IE as their default browser (i mean, not a bylaw but the whole country) since IE6 and never upgraded for almost a decade? and, Windows XP is by far the most installed OS in the world, with ie6 sp1 as the primary browser.

ie6 will be here until 2014 for final users and for goverments, i would add 5 more (at least in LA).

will the world be here by then? who knows, make your work the easier you can. at any cost. 
would your client plus$$ you for your ie6 version? mmm.

on the other hand, would you induce losses to a client because the visitors navigate the www with an obsolete software and you don't "support ie6 anymore"?

its an cyber-educational thing, people will realise one day (maybe prior 2014) that a browser is not a folder.